# How to get key alias from keystore android studio?

Tags: android-studio, keystore

I was trying to generate new signed apk file and got an error: **Invalid keystore format**. Is there the way to get this key alias or not?
When I'm trying to choose key alias - I got a mistake[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if the keystore you saved has the ending name of .jks the Java-Keystore-Format.